# A Database Error Occurred Column 'page_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, web

**A Database Error Occurred**

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'page_id' cannot be null

```
INSERT INTO st_hit (page_id, hit_time) VALUES (NULL, 1486470765)
```

> Filename:database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

**DB_Driver.php**

```
        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            // grab the error number and message now, as we might run some
            // additional queries before displaying the error
            $error_no = $this->_error_number();
            $error_msg = $this->_error_message();

            // We call this function in order to roll-back queries
            // if transactions are enabled.  If we don't call this here
            // the error message will trigger an exit, causing the
            // transactions to remain in limbo.
            $this->trans_complete();

            // Log and display errors
            log_message('error', 'Query error: '.$error_msg);
            return $this->display_error(
                                    array(
                                            'Error Number: '.$error_no,
                                            $error_msg,
                                            $sql
                                        )
                                    ); **(Line 330)**
```

Meanwhile if I check on PHPMyAdmin for the table st_hit, the structure shows like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha16M.jpg)

Please advice what should I do since it should be showing 404 page not found

Besides of that it also shows like below:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/page.php

Line Number: 92

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/page.php

My controllers page php file is like this:

class Page extends MY_Controller {

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('media_model');
    $this->load->library('website');
    //$this->load->library('facebook');
    $this->website->getConfig();
    $this->load->library('analytics');
    /*if ( ! $this->session->userdata('sess_visit'))
    {*/
        $this->analytics->getVisitor_data();
        //$this->session->set_userdata('sess_visit', 1);
    //} 
}

private function getHit_Counter($page_id) {
    if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'admin')
        return FALSE;
    $hitCounter['page_id'] = $page_id;
    $hitCounter['hit_time'] = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    //print_r($hitCounter);
    $this -> db -> insert("st_hit", $hitCounter);
}

function index()
{
    $this->data['page_list_category'] = false;
    $post_category = false;
    $guid = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $this->data['parent'] = 1;
    if ($guid)
    {
        if ( ! $this->data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_guid($guid, 'page'))
            show_404();
```

/*if ( ! $this->data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_guid($guid, 'page'))show_404
                $this->data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_id(1);*/

```
        $this->data['parent'] = $this->page_model->get_parent($this->data['page_detail']->page_id);

        if ($this->data['parent']=='')
            $this->data['parent'] = $this->page_model->get_nav_det($this->data['page_detail']->page_id);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_id(1);
        /* $this->data['product_category'] = $this->page_model->get_extra_post(145,26);
        $this->data['product_list'] = $this->page_model->get_post_by_cat($this->data['product_category'][0]->page_id,true);*/
        $this->data['lightbox1'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(4);
        $this->data['lightbox2'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(5);
        $this->data['lightbox3'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(6);
        /* $this->data['lightbox4'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(5);
        $this->data['lightbox5'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(6);
        $this->data['lightbox6'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(7);
        $this->data['lightbox7'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(8);
        $this->data['lightbox8'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(9);
        $this->data['lightbox9'] = $this->page_model->get_lightbox(10); */
        /*$this->data['home_news'] = $this->page_model->get_archieve(18, false, 3, 0);
        $this->data['post_testi'] = $this->page_model->get_testi_post(1);
        $this->data['post_news'] = $this->page_model->get_child_post(134, 'post');
        $this->data['recipe_week'] = $this->page_model->get_archieve(104, false, 1, 0);
        $this->data['home_testi'] = $this->page_model->limit_result(3, 0); */

        $this->getHit_Counter(1);
        $this->website->page_id = 1;
    }

    $this->data['page_post'] = $this->page_model->get_child_post($this->data['page_detail']->page_id, 'post');
    $this->data['page_banner'] = $this->page_model->get_child_post($this->data['page_detail']->page_id, 'banner');
    $this->data['page_pbanner'] = $this->page_model->get_child_post($this->data['page_detail']->page_id, 'pbanner');
    $this->data['page_category'] = $this->page_model->get_child_post($this->data['page_detail']->page_id, 'category');

    if ($this->uri->segment(3) == 'apply')
    {
        $this->data['post_detail'] = $this->page_model->guid_checking($this->uri->segment(2));
        $this->getHit_Counter($this->data['post_detail']->page_id);
        $this->template->build('page_career_apply', $this->data);
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->uri->segment(2) != '' AND $this->uri->segment(2) != 'archive' AND $this->uri->segment(2) != 'page')
    {
        $guid = $this->uri->segment(2);
        if (!$type = $this->page_model->guid_checking($guid)) {show_404();}
        if ($type->template_type=='post')
        {
            $this->data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->get_child_post_by_guid($guid, 'post');
            $post_category = $this->page_model->get_category_id($this->data['page_detail']->page_id);
            if ($post_category)
            {
                $cat = array();
                foreach ($post_category as $p_cat){
                    $cat[] = $p_cat->category_id;
                }
                $allcat = implode(',', $cat);
                $this->data['random_post'] = $this->page_model->get_random_by_cat($allcat);
            }
        }
        if ($type->template_type=='category')
        {
            $this->data['page_list_category'] = $this->page_model->get_post_by_cat($type->page_id);
        }
    }

    if ($this->data['page_detail']->page_guid == 'testimoni')
    {
        $this->data['post_testi'] = $this->page_model->get_testi_post();
    }

    if ($this->data['page_detail']->page_sidebar == 'Visible' AND $this->data['page_detail']->sidebar_id != 0)
    {
        $sidebar_id = $this->data['page_detail']->sidebar_id;
        $this->data['sidebar_detail'] = $this->page_model->get_sidebar($sidebar_id);
    }
    if ($this->data['page_detail']->template_id==13)
    {
        $this->data['rarchive'] = $this->page_model->get_archive(14);
    }

    $this->getHit_Counter($this->data['page_detail']->page_id);

    /*meta*/
    $this->website->page_id = $this->data['page_detail']->page_id;
    $this->website->getConfig();
    /*end meta*/

    $this->template->build($this->data['page_detail']->template_body, $this->data);
}

function listproduct()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->data['product_list'] = $this->page_model->get_post_by_cat($id,true);
    $this->load->view('page_pp', $this->data);
}

public function sendtestimonial()
{
    $alert = array(
        'alert_state' => 'fail',
        'alert_message' => 'An error occurred.'
    );

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'trim|required|strip_tags');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $data = array(
            'page_id' => '179',
            'comment_author' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'comment_content' => $this->input->post('message'),
            'comment_created' => time(),
            'comment_status' => 'Draft'
        );

        if ($this->page_model->saveTestimonial($data))
        {
            echo "$('.loading').hide();
                $('#alert').hide();
                $('.succ-msg').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Your testimonial has been successfully sent.').fadeOut(5000);
                document.getElementById('testiForm').reset();";
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$('.loading').hide();
                $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Somethings missing. Please try again.').fadeOut(5000);
                document.getElementById('testiForm').reset();";
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $error = '';
            if (form_error('name'))
                $error = 'name';
            else if (form_error('message'))
                $error = 'message';

            if ($error=='message'){
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('" . form_error($error) . "');
                    $('input').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('textarea').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('textarea[name=\"" . $error . "\"]').css({'border':'1px solid #ae1f26'});";
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('" . form_error($error) . "');
                    $('input').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('textarea').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('input[name=\"" . $error . "\"]').css({'border':'1px solid #ae1f26'});";
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}

public function sendcontact()
{
    $alert = array(
        'alert_state' => 'fail',
        'alert_message' => 'An error occurred.'
    );

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'phone', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'trim|required|strip_tags');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            /* SEND MAIL */
            $this->load->library('email');
            $system_info_email = $this->page_model->find_id(24)->page_email;
            $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->to($system_info_email); 
            $this->email->subject('Sekarbumi Contact Us Form');
            $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
            $msg = "Name : ". $this->input->post('name');
            $msg .= "<br/>Email : ". $this->input->post('email');
            $msg .= "<br/>Phone : ". $this->input->post('phone');
            $msg .= "<br/><br/>Message : <br/>";
            $msg .= $this->input->post('message');
            $this->email->message($msg);
            if($this->email->send())
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Your message has been successfully sent and wait for replay.').fadeOut(5000);
                    document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();";
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Error Occurred. Try again later.').fadeOut(5000);
                    document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();";
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $error = "$('input').removeClass('error');$('textarea').removeClass('error');$('.loading').hide();$('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Sorry. Please Fill All Fields.');";
            if (form_error('name'))
                $error .= "$('input[name=\"name\"]').addClass('error');";
            if (form_error('phone'))
                $error .= "$('input[name=\"phone\"]').addClass('error');";
            if (form_error('email'))
                $error .= "$('input[name=\"email\"]').addClass('error');";
            if (form_error('message'))
                $error .= "$('textarea[name=\"message\"]').addClass('error');";

            echo $error;
            exit;
        }
    }
}

public function sendform()
{
    $alert = array(
        'alert_state' => 'fail',
        'alert_message' => 'An error occurred.'
    );

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'full_name', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'gender', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'date', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('month', 'month', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'year', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'address', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'phone', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('education', 'education', 'trim|required|strip_tags');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('about', 'about', 'trim|required|strip_tags');

    $max = $this->input->post('numexp');
    for($i=1;$i<=$max;$i++)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fromperiode'.$i, 'fromperiode'.$i, 'trim|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('untilperiode'.$i, 'untilperiode'.$i, 'trim|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company'.$i, 'company'.$i, 'trim|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('position'.$i, 'position'.$i, 'trim|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('jobdesc'.$i, 'jobdesc'.$i, 'trim|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('salary'.$i, 'salary'.$i, 'trim|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('rol'.$i, 'rol'.$i, 'trim|strip_tags');
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $pathToUploadedFile = '';
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/attach/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('upload_cv'))
        {
            $ret = $this->upload->data();
            $pathToUploadedFile = $ret['full_path'];
        }

        /* SEND MAIL */
        $this->load->library('email');
        $system_info_email = $this->page_model->find_id(180)->page_email;
        $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('full_name'));
        $this->email->to($system_info_email);
        $this->email->subject('Job Application');
        if ($pathToUploadedFile != '')
        {
            $this->email->attach($pathToUploadedFile);
        }
        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
        $msg = "Full Name : ". $this->input->post('full_name');
        $msg .= "<br/>Gender : ". $this->input->post('gender');
        $msg .= "<br/>Date of Birth : ". $this->input->post('date') .'-'. $this->input->post('month') .'-'. $this->input->post('year');
        $msg .= "<br/>Address : ". $this->input->post('address');
        $msg .= "<br/>Phone : ". $this->input->post('phone');
        $msg .= "<br/>Email : ". $this->input->post('email');
        $msg .= "<br/>Education : ". $this->input->post('education');
        $msg .= "<br/>About : <br/>";
        $msg .= $this->input->post('about');
        $msg .= "<br/><br/>Last Job<br/><br/>";
        $max = $this->input->post('numexp');
        for($i=1;$i<=$max;$i++)
        {
            $msg .= "Periode : ". $this->input->post('fromperiode'.$i)." - ".$this->input->post('untilperiode'.$i);
            $msg .= "<br/>Company : ". $this->input->post('company'.$i);
            $msg .= "<br/>Position : ". $this->input->post('position'.$i);
            $msg .= "<br/>Job Description : ". $this->input->post('jobdesc'.$i);
            $msg .= "<br/>Salary : ". $this->input->post('salary'.$i);
            $msg .= "<br/>Reason of Leaving : <br/>";
            $msg .= $this->input->post('rol'.$i)."<br/><br/>";
        }
        $this->email->message($msg);
        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "$('.loading').hide();
                $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Thank you. Your job application has been successfully sent.').fadeOut(5000);
                document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();";
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$('.loading').hide();                     
                $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Error occurred, please try again later.').fadeOut(5000);
                document.getElementById('careerForm').reset();";
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $error = '';
            if (form_error('full_name'))
                {$error = 'full_name';$name = 'full_name';}
            else if (form_error('gender'))
                {$error = 'gender';$name = 'gender';}   
            else if (form_error('date'))
                {$error = 'date';$name = 'date';}
            else if (form_error('month'))
                {$error = 'month';$name = 'month';}
            else if (form_error('year'))
                {$error = 'year';$name = 'year';}
            else if (form_error('address'))
                {$error = 'address';$name = 'address';}
            else if (form_error('phone'))
                {$error = 'phone';$name = 'phone';}
            else if (form_error('email'))
                {$error = 'email';$name = 'email';}
            else if (form_error('about'))
                {$error = 'about';$name = 'about';}
            /* else if (form_error('periode'))
                {$error = 'periode';$name = 'periode';}
            else if (form_error('company'))
                {$error = 'company';$name = 'company';}
            else if (form_error('position'))
                {$error = 'position';$name = 'position';}
            else if (form_error('jobdesc'))
                {$error = 'jobdesc';$name = 'jobdesc';}
            else if (form_error('salary'))
                {$error = 'salary';$name = 'salary';}
            else if (form_error('rol'))
                {$error = 'reason of leaving';$name = 'rol';} */

            if ($error == 'about')
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('" . form_error($error) . "');
                    $('select').parent().find('.select').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('input').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('textarea').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('textarea[name=\"" . $name . "\"]').css({'border':'1px solid #ae1f26'});";
                exit;

            }
            else if ($error == 'date' || $error == 'month' || $error == 'year')
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('" . form_error($error) . "');
                    $('select').parent().find('.select').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('input').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('textarea').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('select[name=\"" . $name . "\"]').parent().find('.select').css({'border':'1px solid #ae1f26'});";
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('" . form_error($error) . "');
                    $('select').parent().find('.select').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('input').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('textarea').css({'border-color':'#dddddd'});
                    $('input[name=\"" . $name . "\"]').css({'border':'1px solid #ae1f26'});";
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}

public function search()
{
    if ($_POST)
    {
        $keyword = trim($this->input->post('search', TRUE));
        redirect('search/' . urlencode(str_replace(array('/','\\','"'), '', $keyword)));
    }

    $key = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $keyword = urldecode($key);
    $search_result = $this->page_model->search_result($keyword);

    /* $total_rows = count($search_result);
    $page = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $limit = 10;

    if ( ! $page OR ! $this->page_model->is_natural_no_zero($page))
    {
        $page = 1;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($total_rows > $limit AND $page > ceil($total_rows / $limit))
            $page = ceil($total_rows / $limit);
        $offset = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
    }

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('search/' . $key . '/page' );
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination reset">';                     
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';                        
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';                        
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';                     
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';                       
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';                     
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';                     
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';                       
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';                      
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';                        
    $config['prev_link'] = '<li><img src="'.site_url("themes/ranchs/assets/images/left-arrow.png").'" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> prev</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '<li>next <img src="'.site_url("themes/ranchs/assets/images/right-arrow.png").'" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></li>';
    $config['first_link'] = FALSE;                      
    $config['last_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['num_links'] = $total_rows;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $first_data = ($page * $limit)-9;
    $last_data = ($page * $limit);
    if ($last_data > $total_rows) $last_data = $total_rows;

    $this->data['search_result'] = $this->page_model->search_result($keyword, $limit, $offset);
    $this->data['total_rows'] = $search_result;
    $this->data['total_rows_count'] = $total_rows;
    $this->data['first_data'] = $first_data;
    $this->data['last_data'] = $last_data;
    $this->data['keyword'] = $keyword; */
    $this->data['search_result'] = $this->page_model->search_result($keyword);
    $this->data['keyword'] = $keyword;

    $this->template->build('search', $this->data);
}

public function newsletter()
{
    $alert = array(
        'alert_state' => 'fail',
        'alert_message' => 'An error occurred.'
    );

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newsletter', 'newsletter', 'trim|required|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $data = array(
                'newsletter_email' => $this->input->post('newsletter'),
                'newsletter_Status' => 'Published'
            );
            if ($this->page_model->cek_newsletter($this->input->post('newsletter')))
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Your email already saved. Please input different email.');
                    document.getElementById('newsletterForm').reset();";
                exit;
            }

            else if ($this->page_model->regis_newsletter($data))
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Your email has been successfully saved.');
                    document.getElementById('newsletterForm').reset();";
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "$('.loading').hide();
                    $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('Somethings missing. Please try again.');
                    document.getElementById('newsletterForm').reset();";
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $error = '';
            if (form_error('newsletter'))
                $error = 'newsletter';

            echo "$('.loading').hide();
                $('#alert').addClass('errorMessage').show().fadeIn(300).html('" . form_error($error) . "');";
            exit;
        }
    }
}

public function signin()
{
    $this->load->view('signin_index', $this->data);
}

public function signindetail()
{
    $this->load->view('under_construction', $this->data);
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: In your table structure page_id is integer and not null so you must enter 0 or any number for page_id

Comment: only show your specific function for getting best answer

Answer (score 0):

You should make your column `Allow NULL` to insert null values into it.
Run below query

```
ALTER TABLE `st_hit` CHANGE `page_id` `page_id` INT(10) NULL;
```

Comment: It works but after that it shows another PHP error was encountered.    
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/page.php

Line Number: 92 and also 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/page.php

Line Number: 109

Comment: you are getting the obejct as null and hence it is giving warning, checkl libne no 109